# php .htaccess rewrite with new cpanel account

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I have the following in my .htaccess file, which I do often for cleaner URL's.  There are pro's and cons to this I know and I think I've found a con.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
Options All -Indexes
```

I've up a new cPanel account for this website so the URL looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/~newuser/
```

...where example.com is my reseller account and newuser is my client.

The site loads fine but when I click a link `http://www.example.com/~newuser/about` I get the following error:

> The requested URL
>   /home/newuser/public_html/about.php
>   was not found on this server.

The problem is, that's exactly the file I want it to display and that is the document root. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this .htaccess in the folder that maps to http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/~newuser

Also - i know it seems obvious but are you requesting http://www.example.com/~newuser/about or http://www.example.com/~newuser/about.php - if its the latter it will add on an extra ".php"

Comment: I'm requesting example.com/~newuser/about and it should show example.com/~newuser/about.php without actually showing the .php in the URL.  The .htaccess is in the folder/~newuser/ (which when we repoint the domain will be the root).

Comment: ok - just checking ;) have you tried disabling the htaccess to confirm that that is the problem - I just tried using your htaccess and it seemed to work fine

Comment: What is the `\ ` in `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php` for? That part is not a regular expression.

Comment: @jeeorse: what other cons you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your `RewriteCond` lines, add a `RewriteBase` line like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~newuser/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: YES! Mark, you saved me ripping hair out. stackoverflow.com, I love you.